# How to apply flex wrap property in div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
            rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col s12">
            <div class="col s6 content-box">
               <div class="subcontent" id="main" >
               </div>
               <!--sub content div for table-->
               <div class="subcontent">
                  <div id="chart1" class="charts">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s6 content-box">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And my using css:

```
.charts {
    height: 162px;
    background-color: #f3eaeacc;
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;  
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

This is the div and I want to use flex wrap property inside. Anyone can suggest to me how?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You have nothing inside of `.charts` so there is no way to tell what you are trying to do. Please edit the question to indicate exactly what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
.subcontent .charts{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;  
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Hope this code block may help.

Comment: Thank you !  I applied this  property inside div but this is not working...

Comment: Can you please share the piece of CSS code you are using.